# how to add comment via facebook connect on iphone

Tags: iphone, facebook

I have been trying to use the comments.add REST api method to add comments to objects. I have all the publish_stream permissions and access_token's but its coming back with a 805.

Anyone know how to get it to work? I'm trying to comment on a photo and I'm passing in its object_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the pid instead of the object_id! It now works.